# Blogger subdomain not redirecting to my custom domain

Tags: blogger, domain

I bought a domain for my blog through Google (which uses GoDaddy to actually get the domains), but it seems like there are some problems. I can't get [yannbane.blogspot.com](http://yannbane.blogspot.com) to redirect to [www.yannbane.com](http://www.yannbane.com).

On this image, one can clearly see how Google states that the redirection will happen:

[image]

But as I've said before, that does not happen at all. I see this as a potential issue because of these things:

1. Readers might get confused.
2. There might be problems with AdSense (there are, actually, as the ads don't get displayed on the blogspot subdomain).
3. Search engines might get confused.
4. In my Google Webmaster tools, there are two "pages" listed, for something that is essentially the same page.

**How can I get Blogger's subdomain to redirect to my domain?**

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. Any idea as to when they'll have a solution?

Comment: It got fixed automagically for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be working (though of course from  myblog.blogspot.com to  www.myblog.com - because myblog.blogger.com does not exist).

There's a post in Blogger's "Known Problems" blog this morning saying that custom-redirects are currently suspended.  This makes me think that there's a fairly serious issue with this feature at present - they don't usually admit to problems!

Ref:    http://knownissues.blogspot.com/2012/09/custom-domains-are-current-non.html

So firstly, you should wait 'til there's an update there saying that the problem is fixed.

After that, then if your re-direct isn't working post then you need to post the details, inlcuding

- your actual blogspot domain name
- your custom domain name
- what happens when you try to do the re-direct

so that someone with experience in checking DNS settings can spot the problem for you.

(I suspect the StackExchange guidelines will not like me referring your to Blogger's Product Forum for this, but my experience is that you will get good assistance there - you may have to bump your query a couple of times if the right people don't see it immediately.)